# Problem uninstalling cgminer in xubuntu

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, uninstall

I have installed cgminer-3.7.2 from sources. I later wanted to remove the package and followed the instructions provided in install guide. But i am still able to run the program when i type in 'cgminer' in the terminal.
How to completely remove the program?

Comment: Is there an uninstall binary in the source? Did you also install it from the repositories?

Comment: yes it has a uninstall binary. No i dont install it from the repositories. But i assumed that I have uninstalled it and delete the folder where i built the package.

Comment: Please don't put `[solved]` in the title, accept the answer already given or add your own answer and accept that (note that it might take a while until you'll be able to accept it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with cgminer, but is it possible that it is still running in the background? In that case, a restart might fix things. Also look at /bin/ or /usr/bin/ (when you install a program, a shell script is usually installed here and executed whenever you run the command) and see if there is a file named "cgminer".

If you uninstalled it using its binary, then there shouldn't be any files left except local user config files (which alone would not allow you to run the command).

Comment: I found a way just typed "sudo make install clean" in the terminal and i was able to completely uninstall it.